# Pass anonymous function to jquery selector expr[:]

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, you can run a selector where every element is run through a function you define, like this (totally contrived example):

```
jQuery.expr[':'].AllOrNothing= function(a,i,m){
    // a is the thing to match, m[3] is the input
    if(m[3] === "true"){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$("div:AllOrNothing(" + true + ")"); //returns all divs
$("div:AllOrNothing(" + false + ")"); //returns nothing
```

Is it possible to pass an anonymous function instead of calling `jQuery.expr[:].Name=` ?

**Edit**

I'm envisioning something chainable like the following:

```
$("div").filterByFunction(function(a,i,m){ ... })
```

Comment: what do you mean? show an example of how your anonymous function should be

Comment: @Ibu does my edit help? I haven't really thought much about what kind of syntax would be possible.

Comment: according to your edit, you're looking for something more like a jQuery plugin than a selector, I think.

Comment: The point is to be able to use it in a chain of selectors. Maybe my example was unhelpful, in English I want to be able to do something like: "Hide all `section` elements that have a child `div` for which this function returns true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to use the built-in `.filter()` method and pass it a custom function that examines sibling elements to decide whether to return true or false and then hide the remaining elements.

```
$("section").filter(function() {
    // examine child div and return true or false
}).hide();
```

Comment: Yikes, I guess I should have figured out that this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you could an implementation of `filter` yourself with by adding to `$.fn`

```
$.fn.customFilter = function(f) {
    var filtered = $();
    this.each(function() {
        if(f.call(this)) {
            filtered = filtered.add(this)
        }
    });
    return filtered;
}

$("div").filterByFunction(function(){ return $(this).text() != "test"; })
```

Not that you should, in this case.